# How to make a embed to the user requirments?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm coding a discord bot and wondering how I would do this

If the user inputs

```
~embed Title Description Colour
```

It will output an embed with the requirements.

How would I do so?

And thanks @André

Heres my code : https://ghostbin.com/paste/uetpj

Comment: Im using the case : break method by the way!

Comment: Still unanswered guys!

Comment: There is an answer already. Don't expect us to make all the code for you, so all you have to do is copy and paste. That way you won't ever learn.

Comment: Yeah but, you didnt explain myString

Comment: I figured it out its **ok**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be with a character that the user needs to use to separate the fields. Like `|` or `;;`. Something the users wont usually type in the messages.
Then you can split the message with that character.

```
var arguments = myString.split('|');
```

And then verify if the user gave all the arguments required:

```
if(arguments && arguments.length == 3){
    // keep going
} else {
    // warn the user that the syntax is wrong
}
```

And finally you would need to generate the Embed.

```
var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
embed.setTitle(arguments[0]);
embed.setDescription(arguments[1]);
embed.setColor(arguments[2]);
```

Comment: It says  '             var arguments = myString.split('|');
                              ^

ReferenceError: myString is not defined'

Comment: Well you need to change myString for what you received from the message

Comment: I've done this at . the moment

`          case "embed":
              var arguments = myString.split('|');
              if(arguments && arguments.length == 3){
             } else {
             message.channel.send("Please finish the arguments. Format : Title|Description|Colour")
             }
             var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed(data);
             embed.setTitle(arguments[0]);
             embed.setDescription(arguments[1]);
             embed.setColor(arguments[2]);
             break;`

Comment: i also just noticed an error, on the `new Discord.RichEmbed()` you don't have `data` to start with. Also i've updated my answer

Comment: you basically need to grab what you have in `message.contents` and remove the prefix and the command

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by change myString to what you received from the message.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You would need to show more code on how to do you have your code structured. And please don't post code into the comments, add it to the answer. Its easier to look at

Comment: I'll remove my bot token :D

Comment: In your case you would need to join the array with the message arguments again, but without the prefix.

Comment: Im really sorry :)

Comment: Hello? You still here?

Comment: Please countinue helping

Comment: Still need help :/