# How to make a console message and command saying how many servers are using the bot and users are using the bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to do a command basically saying, when the bot starts up it says in terminal...

> Bot is running with (users online) users, in  (amount of channels its running in) channels of (servers its running on) guilds!

I've tried using this, but it doesn't work.

```
"Bot is running with "+client.users.size+
" users, in  "+client.channels.size+
" channels of "+client.guilds.size+" guilds! "
```

The error is

> console.log("Bot is running with "+client.users.size+" users, in
> "+client.channels.size+" channels of "+client.guilds.size+" guilds! ");`

> ReferenceError: client is not defined

but it won't work, any ideas?

Also on a command too, I have a basic idea but not much.

```
case "ping":
  message.channel.send("Bot is running! ✅\n Bot is running with "+client.users.size+
 " users, in  "+client.channels.size+" channels of "+client.guilds.size+
 " guilds! ");
 break;
```

Comment: Alright and the thing that you tried what is the result?

Comment: Any console messages? The code you have provided does not tell us anything about what can be the issue. Perhaps the vars are uninitialised?

Comment: I added the error, reload.

Comment: Well then you need to stop copy and pasting code from the internet without you actually understand it. It [works](https://i.imgur.com/iUN6mpK.png) on my end.

Comment: Based on the code you uploaded on a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50832535/6195472) question instead of `client` you need to use `bot`

Comment: Worked thanks! Please post as a answer for others, or I could answer myself. But i'm assuming you want credit so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Discord.JS guides use the variable `client` as the bot, where you can get all the data from. Some others use `bot`.
This is just a simple case to check what variable are you using to login the bot with.
If you have `client.login("mytoken")` then you should always use `client`, if you're using `bot.login("mytoken")` then you need to use `bot`.

Please don't copy and paste code from the internet, without actually knowing what it does. It makes questions like this that if you took more attention wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Ok sorry, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

console.log('GameAbout is online! And Present In ' + `${client.guilds.cache.size}` + 'Servers');

This Is The Answer

Use " ` " Around  ${client.guilds.cache.size}